# Why doesn't beep work in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I've tried the below shell, but nothing happened.

```
#! /bin/sh 

beep -f 500 -l 700 
beep -f 480 -l 400 
beep -f 470 -l 250 
beep -f 530 -l 300 -D 100 
beep -f 500 -l 300 -D 100 
beep -f 500 -l 300 
beep -f 400 -l 600 
beep -f 300 -l 500 
beep -f 350 -l 700 
beep -f 250  -l 600
```

I issued the `beep` command in terminal, but again nothing happened. What am I doing wrong? Is there something here that I'm missing?

---

**EDIT:** Here's the output of `sudo modprobe pcspkr -vvv`

```
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:519 kmod_module_new_from_lookup: input alias=pcspkr, normalized=pcspkr
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:525 kmod_module_new_from_lookup: lookup modules.dep pcspkr
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:542 kmod_search_moddep: use mmaped index 'modules.dep' modname=pcspkr
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:390 kmod_pool_get_module: get module name='pcspkr' found=(nil)
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:398 kmod_pool_add_module: add 0xb8adf2b8 key='pcspkr'
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:184 kmod_module_parse_depline: 0 dependencies for pcspkr
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:546 kmod_module_new_from_lookup: lookup pcspkr=0, list=0xb8adf340
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:435 kmod_module_unref: kmod_module 0xb8adf2b8 released
libkmod: DEBUG ../libkmod/libkmod.c:406 kmod_pool_del_module: del 0xb8adf2b8 key='pcspkr'
libkmod: INFO ../libkmod/libkmod.c:319 kmod_unref: context 0xb8adf140 released
```

Comment: Well, it might be a number of things. First you should make sure that your computer does indeed have a system speaker, as many modern computers don't have one any more.

Comment: @arnefm I've attached a headphone to my PC and I can hear music from it. The problem is not from sound card or speaker.

Comment: The pc speaker is not your headphone or sound card. It's a little beeper on the motherboard.

Comment: @Leiaz, thanks for the input. I cannot hear any beep from motherboard.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/19906/367990

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The likeliest reason is that the module that manages your motherboard speakers is not loaded. Blacklisting this module is one of the first things I do on a new install and I wouldn't be surprised if you've either done so yourself and forgot about it or if your distribution does it automatically. Anyway, chances are that you can get your beep working if you run

```
sudo modprobe pcspkr
```

And then try the `beep` again.

Comment: No beep sound from speaker.

Comment: @phpGeek hmm. And the module was loaded correctly? Perhaps it has a different name on your machine.

Comment: I ran it with verbose, you can see the output in the *EDIT* part.

Comment: After a while though in another machine it worked as expected by using `modprobe pcspkr`

Comment: This is not true for all machines

Comment: `Blacklisting this module is one of the first things I do...` Why?

Comment: @RTF because having my computer beep at me is extremely annoying. Especially when I have speakers connected and the beep can be very loud.